# What's faster: catting a bunch of files and then grepping the result, or grepping a bunch of files and then catting the results?

Tags: bash, unix, grep, cat

I have 30 files of ~10GB each. I want my end result to be a single file which is the result of extracting the IP addresses from these 30 files (implemented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/202818/what-regular-expression-can-i-use-to-match-an-ip-address)). What would be faster: using `cat` to combine the files into a single file and then using `grep` on that one file, or using `grep` on 30 files and then using `cat` to combine the newly created 30 files.

Comment: why not profile it for us and let us know? :)

Comment: I cannot think of a reason why there would be any significant difference.

Comment: Why would you want to create 30 separate output files and then combine them with cat?

Answer (score 5):

That's a useless use of `cat`. Just `grep -h "findme" file1 file2 file30 > newfile`

Comment: Probably want to use `grep -h` to suppress printing `file1:`, etc, at the start of each line of output.